# TexShop: do I still need texlive via MacPorts?

Tags: texlive, texshop

In the past I have used TeX Live on my Mac, installed through MacPorts (including several additional packages). I'm a fan of command line, so I typically create my PS/PDF files through the usual commands: `latex`, `bibtex`, `dvips`, or `pdflatex` depending on need.

I have now installed TeXShop on my Mac, and wondering: Do I still need to install TeX Live? I guess not? Did the installation of TeXShop is such that all libraries are accessible when I use `latex`, `bibtex`, `dvips`, `pdflatex` ... from command line? Or do I need to add TeXShop to the path into my `.profile`? How do I do that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your write-up has left me scratching my head. TeXshop is an editor and a front-end to a TeX distribution -- usually, but not necessarily, TeXLive/MacTeX. (Based on your posting, it would appear that you prefer the command line interface and hence don't use the front-end capabilities of TeXshop.) In contrast, TeXLive is a TeX distribution. A front-end such as TeXshop is of little use if no back-end is installed. A separate comment: You don't mention [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/) in your posting; is there a reason for this omission?

Comment: I've seen mentioned in many 9laced that the macports version is not recommended. A latex editor cannot work (or at least cannot convert code to pdf) without a latex installation of some sort. Unless you have severe space restrictions, mactex is the easiest latex distribution to install across all platforms, so I see no reason not to use it. Do remember to update it after installation though (thst is the price of the ease of installation)

Comment: You need to tell TeXShop where your binaries are located. Look for the Path Settings for (pdf)TeX in the Engine tab in TeXShop->Preferences.

Comment: Hi Mico, Thanks. You are right that I prefer working with command line interface. I dealt with macports in the past, but it seems not the preferred choice anymore, as daleif pointed out. Thanks for pointing MacTex, I missed it. Does MacTex provide all the back-end texlive that macports would come with?

Comment: Install MacTex with the yearly provided .pkg file and it installs all the GUIs needed such as TeXShop and configures all the needed paths, etc. Then run the newly installed TeX Live Utility.app to update all the TeX Live stuff and you are done. Tell MacPorts to uninstall whatever TeX stuff you installed using it, to save space and resources keeping it up to date. You will end up with some duplication if MacPorts packages need TeX components to do their thing, but storage is fairly inexpensive these days.